Sum up all hours from the same day in Google Sheets
I'm trying to sum up all hours for the same day row by row. So in column 'F' I want to add the hours of the day. But I cannot use a direct cell reference like 'E4'. The reason is that I use IFTTT to add a row each time I trigger it.
That's why I tried working around with an indirect offset like so:
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-3)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-3));
   INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-3));
   INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)))

Can anyone help?
Link to Google Sheets file you can edit
The table looks like this:


To include additional data in your formulas, use array formulas with infinite ranges such as A2:A, and place your formulas in the header row so you can sort and modify your data without affecting the formulas.
Looking at your source data there is only a single column of hardcoded data which are datetime text strings that don't match valid date formats.
Formula
I didn't tackle your regex and I'm sure my code is fairly inefficient and could be reduced however you can sort your column A data (A2:A) and it will not break the formula the values will sort with it.
Link to sheet Blindspots in your spreadsheet
=INDEX(LET(range;A2:A; _rows;COUNTA(range);
  oRng;offset(range;;;_rows);
  seq;sequence(_rows); ico;IF(ISODD(seq);"";"");
  hdr;{"Start/Stop"\"String-Datestamp"\"Elapsed"\"Daily Total"};
  rgx;lambda(str; let(
    min; regexextract(str; ":(\d+)"); 
    mo; MATCH(regexextract(str; "[A-z]{3}"); 
      {"Jan"; "Feb"; "Mar"; "Apr"; "May"; "Jun"; 
       "Jul"; "Aug"; "Sep"; "Oct"; "Nov"; "Dec"}; 0); 
    hr; regexextract(str; "(\d+):") + 12 * regexmatch(str; "PM$");  
    VALUE(join("-"; regexextract(str; "\d{4}"); mo;
      regexextract(str; "\d+"))) + TIME(hr; min; 0))); 
  srt;sort(map(oRng; row(oRng); lambda(t; r; {rgx(t)\r})));
  t;INDEX(srt;;1); dt;day(t); 
  dur;MAP(seq;t; LAMBDA(x;y; IF(ISODD(x);;y-INDEX(t;x-1)))); 
  dSum;MAP(unique(dt); lambda(u; {xmatch(u;dt;;-1)\sum((dt=u)*dur)}));
  ifna(vstack(hdr; 
    sort({ico\ t\ dur\ vlookup(seq; dSum; 2;0)}; INDEX(srt;;2);1)))))


Sample Data
I modified your data slightly to add an additional day (28th) and remove the orphan row October 27, 2023 at 03:14PM at the top that you had marked "stopped" as it makes no sense to have an end time when there was no start time.




A




1
Date and time


2
October 27, 2023 at 03:15PM


3
October 27, 2023 at 03:15PM


4
October 27, 2023 at 03:26PM


5
October 27, 2023 at 03:34PM


6
October 27, 2023 at 03:34PM


7
October 27, 2023 at 03:35PM


8
October 27, 2023 at 03:35PM


9
October 27, 2023 at 03:37PM


10
October 28, 2023 at 03:37PM


11
October 28, 2023 at 03:53PM


12
October 28, 2023 at 03:54PM


13
October 28, 2023 at 04:12PM



